# FileDrop.js and laravel routes

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-routing, filedrop.js

I am trying to use FileDrop.js (latest version) along with Laravel 5.1 in order to upload files.

I have set a route for the ajax request inside routes.php:

`Route::any('/fileupload/ajax', ['as' => 'fileupload.ajax', 'uses' => 'FileUpload@ajaxRequest']);`

and that jquery code to catch file drop in my respective blade:

```
$('.filedrop')
     .filedrop()
     .on('fdsend', function (e, files) {
         var ajaxUrl = '{{ route('fileupload.ajax') }}';
         //code here
         files.invoke('sendTo', ajaxUrl);
     })
     .on('filedone', function (e, file) {
         //code here
     });
```

The problem is that ajax call returns Laravel's "Page not found!".

It seems like FileDrop.js bypass laravel routing.

Any ideas.

Comment: Try changing `/fileupload/ajax` to `fileupload/ajax`, I don't think the first slash should be there

Comment: @Fester It is absolutely the same.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to the route with your browser?

Comment: @Fester It works, returns FileUpload@ajaxRequest as it should be. The problem is that seems like FileDrop bypasses laravel routing.

Comment: There's no way to 'bypass' laravel routing, all laravel routing does is provide endpoints in the form of URL's which are connected to controller functions

Comment: Try using `url('fileupload/ajax')` instead of `route('fileupload.ajax')`. Also, is your jquery sending a post request? In that case you need to include a csrf token

Comment: @Fester You are right, thank you. It was lack of csrf token that caused that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This question was solved in the comments but Im reposting the answer here for completeness sake.*

Giorgos forgot to send a `CSRF token` with the POST request, Laravel requires this by default on all POST request as is explained in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection).